# Trigger - mysql

Tags: mysql, magento, triggers

```
CREATE TRIGGER ProductStatusHistory_3 
AFTER UPDATE ON catalog_product_entity_int
FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
  IF (OLD.value <> NEW.value)THEN
   INSERT INTO tbl_product_status_history(entity_id,oldvisible,newvisible,datetime) values(NEW.entity_id,OLD.value,NEW.value,NOW());
  END IF;
END;
```

Its not working,

**Error**

> #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 5

Answer (score 0):

You need a delimiter

```
delimiter //

CREATE TRIGGER ProductStatusHistory_3 
AFTER UPDATE ON catalog_product_entity_int
FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
  IF (OLD.value <> NEW.value) THEN
   INSERT INTO tbl_product_status_history
   (entity_id,oldvisible,newvisible,datetime)    
   values
   (
     NEW.entity_id,OLD.value,NEW.value,NOW()
    );
  END IF;
END;//

delimiter ;
```